# Get rows where DATETIME column has entries between certain times

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains a column with DATETIME stamps. I need to return all rows where the time is between 19:00:00 and 20:59:59 regardless of the date.
I understand that I probably need to convert the data in the column that contains DATETIME data to time only using DATE_FORMAT but am struggling to formulate the query properly.
Thanks for any help

Comment: Come on. Try something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from the_table
where 
cast(DATE_FORMAT(col,'%H:%i:%s') as time) between cast('19:00:00' as time) and cast('20:59:59' as time)
```

Comment: while this may answer the question, is better if you add some text explaining what your code does